# Why is self.render() not working? The front can not receive my message

Tags: python, html, tornado

Everything is working fine except that sending a message to the front in self.render of post.
Besides the code after self.render() was running as well. Was this connection shut down? There was no exception happening at all in the backend.

```
class ListsHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            print('get')
            agent_id = self.get_argument('agent_id', None)
            answer_sql = 'select id,value from answer_list'
            cursor.execute(answer_sql)
            answer_results = cursor.fetchall()
            question_sql = 'select id,value from question_list'
            cursor.execute(question_sql)
            question_results = cursor.fetchall()
            answer_results=list(answer_results)
            question_results = list(question_results)
            print 'answer:',answer_results
            print 'question',question_results

            self.render("lists.html", agent_id=agent_id, answer_results=answer_results, question_results=question_results)

        def post(self):

            id = self.get_argument('id', None)
            id=int(id)
            agent_id = self.get_argument('agent_id')  
            if id:
                id-=1
                new_id=id-1
                print(agent_id, id)
                cursor.execute('delete from question_list where id=%s' % (id))
                cursor.execute('update question_list set id=id-1 where id>%s' % (id))
                cursor.execute('delete from answer_list where id=%s' % (id))
                cursor.execute('update answer_list set id=id-1 where id>%s' % (id))
                db.commit()
                answer_sql = 'select id,value from answer_list'
                cursor.execute(answer_sql)
                answer_results = cursor.fetchall()
                question_sql = 'select id,value from question_list'
                cursor.execute(question_sql)
                question_results = cursor.fetchall()
                question_dict[agent_id] = question_results
                self.render("lists.html", agent_id=agent_id, answer_results=answer_results,
                            question_results=question_results)
```

[image]

As you can see, GET  and self.render in GET same as the one in POST work. Only this failed, strange.
And I send a 404 to the front. The browser recieves without any operation.

[image]
Is there anything wrong with my html?

[image]

Comment: The first image shows a `GET` request. Are you sure that you are running the code in `post()` at all?

Comment: Sorry,wrong pic. I doubt that the connection was shut down for timeout. Other handlers using this method was working fine.

Comment: When you say that the "front can not receive my message", do you mean that the browser does not receive HTML content at all (empty page)?

Comment: @SvenFester The browser recevie HTML from GET correctly. But when I click a button and want to refresh my page with POST . It didn't work.

Comment: I think I can see the problem: You are not supplying the parameter "id", thus id is None and the code including the `render` method is never executed.

Comment: Id is not None, it's got from the webpage and the database operatrion are all executed even the code after render such as print. So I think this render order is sent but not recevied by the remote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179441/discussion-between-sven-festersen-and-yuguang).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help from Sven Festersen.
Ajax isn't recieving my data from backend of render. So problom solved in an easy way.

```
def post(self):
    # id为此条问答的id，是lists中显示的id-1
    id = self.get_argument('id', None)
    agent_id = self.get_argument('agent_id')  # 获取用户场景id
    pn = self.get_argument('pn', 1)
    pn = int(pn)
    if id:
        id = int(id)
        id-=1
        new_id=id-1
        cursor.execute('delete from question_list where id=%s' % (id))
        cursor.execute('update question_list set id=id-1 where id>%s' % (id))
        cursor.execute('delete from answer_list where id=%s' % (id))
        cursor.execute('update answer_list set id=id-1 where id>%s' % (id))
        db.commit()
```

And html is the key for this.

```
<script>
            $(function(){
                $('#navHeight').height($(document).height()-85);
                $('#table').on('click','tr .del',function(){
                    var id=$(this).attr('data-id');
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'http://10.240.100.38:8888/lists.html?agent_id='+{{agent_id}},
                        type:"POST",
                        data:{_method:"POST",id:id},
                        success : function(data) {
                            location.reload(true);
                        }
                    })
                })
            })
        </script>
```

I changed the script rather than using a render function.